# Recording the minimum absolute deviation, but including its sign

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, calculated-columns

i have a pandas df in the following form:

| first deviation | second deviation | closest deviation | column name of smallest deviation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.5 | NaN | -0.5 | first deviation |
| -0.4 | -0.8 | -0.4 | first deviation |

*closest deviation* and *column name of smalles deviation* are calculated columns of the first two columns. The table lists the desired outcome, however I haven't found a solution to get to the desired outcome.

The deviation columns show deviations in between two functions and an input function. I want to find out which function is closer to 0 in its deviation and secondly, I want to record the deviation.

Now, if I use `df.abs().idxmin(axis = 1)`, I get the right value for *column name of smallest deviation*, but using `df.abs().min(axis = 1)` then for *closest deviation* logically returns 0.4 and not -0.4. using only `df.min(axis=1)` would then however return -0.8 for *closest deviation*, which also is not correct.

How do I get the correct information including the correct sign?

Thanks already!

Comment: hi @Paul1911, i guess in the desired outcome, bottom right value should also read *first deviaton*, right?

Comment: Hi Mustafa, yes, correct. Thanks, I've adjusted it :)

Comment: thanks. I tried to write an answer as far as I understood, hope it helps.

Comment: It did help, thank you very much! It's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the indices of the closests with your way, we can index into the dataframe to get the corresponding values:

```
# your way for indexes
inds = df.abs().idxmin(axis=1)

# for values: either this (being deprecated..)
vals = df.lookup(df.index, inds)

# or this with numpy's "fancy" indexing
vals = df.to_numpy()[np.arange(len(df)), df.columns.get_indexer(inds)]

# then putting to frame
df["closest deviation"] = vals
df["column name of smallest deviation"] = inds
```

to get

```
   first deviation  second deviation  closest deviation column name of smallest deviation
0             -0.5               NaN               -0.5                   first deviation
1             -0.4              -0.8               -0.4                   first deviation
```

---

note:

[`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) is getting deprecated so other way is to go to numpy domain and index there. Since `inds` are column names but numpy doesn't know them, we get their integer locations with `get_indexer`.